# Python 2.7 and 3.5

Tags: macos, python-2.7, pip, python-3.5

I want to install the latest python version. But I also need to install packages like `quandl` and `pandas`. I used pip and pip freeze to make sure I had them. But when I run python3 it says it does not exist, and when I run python2.7 only pandas was installed. Where those module installed? How can I make all my future modules to be installed into python3 only?

Comment: Pip for python2 does not install for python3 and vice-versa, if you installed for python2 and you cannot see a package you most likely have multiple python2 installs

Comment: you could use virtualenv to create python2 or python3 envs, then activate the environment and pip normally to install your packages. `virtualenv -p python3 envname; . ./envname/bin/activate; pip install ...`. HTH

Comment: You might find some help from [pyenv](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv). It allows you to run multiple versions of python, and it is available from [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) which probably should be using if you're not doing so already.